# Select data rows with condition Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia, erlang-shell

I am new to erlang. I have following data record.

```
-record(tracked_connection, {id,node,vhost,name,pid,protocol,type,peer_host,peer_port,username,connected_at}).
```

I need to select data in following SQL format

```
Select * from tracked_connection where username = 'xxxxx';
```

All rows can get following code.

```
mnesia:select(Tab,[{'_',[],['$_']}]).
```

How I achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
mnesia:select(Tab,[{#tracked_connection{username = "xxxxx", _ = '_'},[],['$_']}]).
```

That is, in the [match spec](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html), the username field of the record must match "xxxxx", while all other fields can be anything.

Comment: Totally working my requirement. Thank you very much. :)